# Changing MATLAB mex build directory

Tags: python, c++, matlab, mex

I’m going to explain a MATLAB mex-tutorial example that is successful.
In my home directory, I have a c-file “/home/yprime.c”. I want to create MATLAB-executable (mex) file (or .mex64 format). This example only requires MATLAB library and include directories. MATLAB knows where these are located and the below statement returns a mex file (.mex64 format) successfully in the home directory.

`>> mex yprime.c`

Now, I’m going to explain my more complicated but actual problem.
In my home directory, I have a cpp-file “/home/example.cpp”. This file requires Python include directories (for header files) and I will be using `–I` options. Unfortunately, this directory is on a root branch (i.e. /root/directory/Python/lib).

The below statement is executed from my */home* directory.
The statement below returns that it can’t find the python header and fails.

`>> mex example.cpp –I/directory/Python/include`

The below statement is executed from my root directory.
The statement below returns that it can’t write the example.o (object file) to the root directory because I don’t have permissions.

`>> mex /home/example.cpp –I/directory/Python/include`

**Is there a way to change where MATLAB is building the object file?**

*Adding paths to MATLAB and giving a relative path to the python include directory were not successful.*

Comment: trust me, use Makefile

Comment: Did you try the -outdir option?

Comment: I just tried the `-c` option (creates the object file but not a MEX-file). I do not have problems compiling.
As for the `-outdir` option, it doesn't work as expected. It has a problem find the header files again (regardless of where I try to compile).

Comment: Try the Verbose option -v to see what paths are being picked up. Also -I needs the absolute path, so make sure you are setting that correctly.

Comment: user3528438, I'm using a mexopts.sh to compile. This looks similar to the makefile examples I'm seeing. Is there an option in the mexopts that I can change for it to see the python libraries/header files?

Comment: Manny, I've used the verbose option (also with the the -n). It shows that the command being executed with g++ with the full path for MATLAB and python library/header directories. MATLAB and python directories are in very similar locations, but when executed form the home directory python is not recognized.

Comment: I usually do `sudo make all` to work around permission problem. It's worth trying running matlab with `sudo`, or run `mex` with `sudo`.